# Three js texture offset not updating

Tags: three.js

I am currently trying to create a mesh that is colored using a datatexture, my initial coloring shows up just fine, but now my next goal is to offset the texture along the y axis. very similar to this example.

http://math.hws.edu/graphicsbook/demos/c5/textures.html

How I create my texture / mesh:

```
this.colorTexture = new DataTexture(colors, this.frameWidth, frameCount, RGBFormat, FloatType, UVMapping, RepeatWrapping, RepeatWrapping);

    const material = new MeshBasicMaterial({
        side: FrontSide,
        vertexColors: true,
        wireframe: false,
        map: this.colorTexture
    });
    
    this.mesh = new Mesh(geometry, material);
```

How I attempt to animate the texture using offset:

```
    this.mesh.material.map.offset.y -= 0.001;
    this.mesh.material.map.needsUpdate = true;
    this.mesh.material.needsUpdate = true;
    this.mesh.needsUpdate = true;
```

I have confirmed that the function I'm using to try to offset is being called during each animation frame, however the visualization itself is not animating or showing changes apart from the initial positioning of the colors I wrote to the texture.
Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uv transformation matrix of a texture is updated automatically as long as [Texture.matrixAutoUpdate](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/textures/Texture.matrixAutoUpdate) is set to `true` (which is also the default value). You can simply modulate `Texture.offset`. There is no need to set any `needsUpdate` flags (`Mesh.needsUpdate` does not exist anyway).

It's best if you strictly stick to the code from the [webgl_materials_texture_rotation](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_texture_rotation) example. If this code does not work, please demonstrate the issue with a live example.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I recreated the issue in this code pen where I generate a geometry / mesh very similarly and added in a line in the middle of the texture that should just be moving up the Y axes and eventually wrapping around.

https://codepen.io/samantha-palmer/pen/ZEpQKow?editors=0010

Comment: Your geometry has no `uv` attribute. Without texture coordinates, you can't use textures.

Comment: Did some more reading into uvs, generated a set of uvs for my geometry and it worked! Thank you very much. For those running into a very similar issue here is my fixed code.
https://codepen.io/samantha-palmer/pen/ZEpQKow?editors=0010